# A question about triangles. You have to find the number of ways to complete a series so as to complete the diagram

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

[This is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dtT6.png)

[image]

My approach:

I labeled all the empty triangles as different variables a,b,c,d,e,f.
Now since 1,4,6,10 have already been labeled, I am trying to make equations so that the sum is equal, however only one small triangle, the middle triangle is common to all and I am not understanding how to get to a single answer, let alone finding the total number of ways.

I am not understanding the proper approach to this question

An approach to this question would be appreciated.

Comment: Whatever is the central number, the remaining parts in each triangle have the same total sum. The triangles are three. Can you continue with this hint?